# Prove that $v_2(x_n) = v_2(n)$

Tags: number-theory

> Given positive integers $a,b,c$ and the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ defined by $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 2a+1, x_{n+2} = 2(2b+1)x_{n+1}-(2c+1)x_n$, prove that $v_2(x_n) = v_2(n)$.

An example of such a sequence with $2a+1 = 2b+1 = 2c+1 = 3$ would be \begin{align*}x_0 &= 0\\ x_1 &= 3\\ x_2 &= 6 \cdot 3-3 \cdot 0 = 18\\x_3 &= 6 \cdot 18-3 \cdot 3 = 99 \\x_4 &= 99 \cdot 6-3 \cdot 18 = 540 \\x_5 &= 6 \cdot 540-3 \cdot 99 = 2943\\ x_6 &= 6 \cdot 2943-3 \cdot 540 = 16038\\x_7 &= 6 \cdot 16038-3 \cdot 2943 = 87399\\x_8 &= 6 \cdot 87399-3 \cdot 16038 = 476280
\end{align*} and we have that $v_2(x_n) = v_2(n)$ for each of these.

I thought about proving the result in general by strong induction on $n$. For $n = 0,1$ the result is true. Now suppose that it is true for all $1 \leq i \leq n+1$. We first take the case that $n+1$ is odd.

If $n+2 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, then since by hypothesis $x_n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ we have $x_{n+2} \equiv 2(2b+1)x_{n+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$.

How can we solve the $n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ case?

Comment: How is number-theoretic function $v_2$ defined?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin It is the largest power of $2$ dividing $n$.